# How to add certificate for remote repository in JFrog Artifactory

Tags: maven, repository, ssl-certificate, artifactory

Could you please help me to use JFrog Artifactory certificates feature. (Admin -> Certificates).

I want to add certificate for a maven repository (https://plugins.jenkins.io/repository)

Below are the steps I followed –

- Step1: Downloaded the certificate (DER encoded binary X.509) for this repository from chrome browser.
- Step2: Converted certificate extension from .cer to .pem. Directly converted extension from .cer to .pem and tried with open ssl also `openssl x509 -inform der -in certificate.cer -out certificate.pem`
- Step3: Add new certificate via  (Admin -> Certificates -> New -> Drag and dropped .pem file), Entered Certificate Alias name.

After clicking on Save, I am getting below error –

```
Certificate could not be added. Unable to read the provided PEM file. Missing private key or certificate.
```

Other important information –

- When I researched more on this error, I found jfrog is expecting certificate and private key both in .pem file. When I am downloading certificate from chrome I am getting only certificate but not private key.
  https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-to-resolve-the-certificate-could-not-be-added-unable-to-read-the-provided-pem-file-missing-key-or-certificate/
- I have tried the above steps with Base-64 encoded X.509 certificate also but results are same.

Comment: Can you please explain your use case? 
What is the reason you are trying to add the certificate?
The steps you are trying are for client certificate.

Comment: I am adding certificate so that when Artifactory access a remote repository, it will secure the connection using client certificate.
I want to use it as a replacement of adding certificate in JVM Key store as it is easy to maintain via Artifactory.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is adding client certificate.
Meaning that when Artifactory will access a remote repository, it will secure the connection using client certificate.

If your problem is that Artifactory does not trust the certificate exposed by the remote repo (https://plugins.jenkins.io/repository) then you need to follow the directions here:

https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Using+a+Self-Signed+Certificate

More explanations about the differences:

https://www.websecurity.symantec.com/security-topics/client-certificates-vs-server-certificates

Please elaborate a little bit more about the original problem you had, so we could understand if you are picking the right solution.

Good luck.

Comment: i added remote repository certificate into Admin - Security - Certificates. After adding i mapped certificate to remote repository in Edit repository - Advanced - SSL/TLS certificate
But when i make the connection, it doesn't pick up the certificate from artifactory. It looks that it is still going into JVM Keystore for certificate and Keystore might contains the expired certificate for this repository which cause the connection to fail with error 
Connection to remote repository failed: PKIX path building failed:sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find vali

Comment: Complete error message -
Connection to remote repository failed: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Answer (score 1):

Your certificate probably came from a CSR (certificate request)?

You should have a private key within that CSR request file. Simply paste the output CER text (enclosed by ----- BEGIN CERTIFICATE  ... -----END CERTIFICATE) - ie your issued certificate, a blank line, then the similar  ---- BEGIN PRIVATE KEY ... ---- END PRIVATE KEY section from the CSR into a simple file called < whatever >.PEM and put that into jfrog. I told Jfrog just yesterday that this part is not clear, and could be expressed more simply in their wiki. What its complaining about is the lack of a PRIVATE KEY entry in the PEM. It took me a while to realise this, and where to get it from.

Comment: Why would Artifactory ever need a private key as a client? Shouldn't just a public key be enough for it to validate authenticity?

Comment: @HNeiva I have no idea at all. Perhaps there is an idea for extension with private decrypt of messages in the future.